# SAS Macro operations

Tags: macros, sas, sum

I need to create sum of 4 variables multiple times each time with new set of variables. For e.g. A1=sum(a1,a2,a3,a4),B1=sum(b1,b2,b3,b4) & so on. So , I am trying to write a macro that will help me do it easily. Following is the code:

```
%macro SUM2(VAR1,var2,var3,VAR4);
data Subs_60_new;
set Subs_60;
substr(&var1,1,10)=sum(&var1,&var2,&var3,&var4);
run;
%mend sum2;
options mprint mlogic;sum2(ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q1,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q2,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q3,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q4);
```

I am using SAS EG for the same & when I run the macro I get the following note:

```
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
```

& obviously when I try to execute the macro it throws an error.

Can some one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

when calling a macro, you need to precede the macro name with a `%` symbol, eg as follows:

```
%macro SUM2(VAR1,var2,var3,VAR4);
data Subs_60_new;
set Subs_60;
substr(&var1,1,10)=sum(&var1,&var2,&var3,&var4);
run;
%mend sum2;
options mprint mlogic;
%sum2(ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q1,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q2,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q3,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q4);
```

The `NOTE` is harmless.  It is `ERROR`s and `WARNING`s in general that you should be concerned with.

I'd point out that this will probably still throw an error, as you are trying to replace characters in a variable (`&var1`) that appears as though it should contain a numeric field (being part of a `sum` function).  Given your description of what you are trying to achieve, I'd suggest adding the new variable name as another macro parameter - as follows:

```
%macro SUM2(VAR1,var2,var3,VAR4,varname);
data Subs_60_new;
set Subs_60;
&varname=sum(&var1,&var2,&var3,&var4);
run;
%mend sum2;
options mprint mlogic;
%sum2(ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q1,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q2
  ,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q3,ADDITIONAL_INFO_Q4
  ,MyNewVariable);
```